# Azure Queue trigger for Azure Functions: configure minimum polling interval

Tags: azure, azure-functions, task-queue, azure-queues

I need to process a task queue and I wonder if Azure Queue will work for my case. Task execution implies querying a rate-limited API and for that reason I want polling to happen every X seconds (can be slower, but must not be faster than that). Azure Function app would consume queue messages with concurrency of 1.

In the [host.json settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-queue-output?tabs=csharp#hostjson-settings) `maxPollingInterval` can be configured. For the minimum interval it says

> Minimum is 00:00:00.100 (100 ms) and increments up to 00:01:00 (1 min)

Is there any way to force the required delay between polls?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The azure queue may not meet your need. Here is the [polling algorithm](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-queue-trigger?tabs=csharp#polling-algorithm):

- When a message is found, the runtime waits two seconds and then
  checks for another message
- When no message is found, it waits about four seconds before trying
  again.
- After subsequent failed attempts to get a queue message, the wait
  time continues to increase until it reaches the maximum wait time(maxPollingInterval),
  which defaults to one minute.

So it does not poll the queue every X seconds.

You may consider using [timer trigger function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-timer?tabs=csharp) which can be specified to run at every X seconds; and inside the function, you can write your logic to call the api.

Comment: I'm accepting this answer since it's what I'll probably do. Had some issues with running a timer function locally on Mac, but now it's [resolved](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64492604/2579733). There may still be an Azure Queue involved for passing tasks to the timer func. For the whole picture there seems to be an alternative solution of deploying a queue-triggered function with `functionAppScaleLimit=1` setting combined with a batch limit of 1 which will wait the required X seconds before exiting. Timer trigger is simpler though and works for my needs at the moment.